# A basic question about $\Rightarrow$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, peano-axioms

I am a beginner in mathematical logic. Sometimes I find expressions like the following

$$\textrm{PA}\vdash A\implies \textrm{PA}\vdash B\tag{$\star$}$$

For example, in Hilbert-Bernays-Lob derivability conditions, I find: $$\textrm{PA}\vdash A\implies \textrm{PA}\vdash\Box A$$

I wonder what the difference is between $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$?

$$\textrm{PA}\vdash A\to B\tag{$\star\star$}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ($*$) says that if Peano Arithmetic (PA) proves $A$, then it also proves $B$. ($**$) says that PA proves that $A$ implies $B$. $\rightarrow$ is part of the language, $\Rightarrow$ of the meta-language.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I wonder if $(*)$ holds, does $(**)$ hold? And vice versa, if $(**)$ holds, does $(*)$ hold?

Comment: If ($**$) holds, then so does ($*$): if PA proves $A\rightarrow B$, then if it also proves $A$, it can plainly prove $B$ by Modus Ponens.

Comment: So, in the case of $(*)$, the application of $(*)$ necessarily presupposes $\textrm{PA}\vdash A$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets do an example with something other than $\textrm{PA}$.

Say $\textrm{GT}$ is group theory.  Say $A$ is "$\forall x, x^2 = e$", that is, every element has order $1$ or $2$.  Say $B$ is "$\forall x, x^3 = e$", that is, every element has order $1$ or $3$.

Now $\textrm{GT} \vdash A$ and $\textrm{GT} \vdash B$ are both false.  (Group $\mathbb Z/5$ fails both properties, so of course $\textrm{GT}$ cannot prove either one.)  Thus

$$
\textrm{GT}\vdash A\;\Longrightarrow\; \textrm{GT}\vdash B\quad\quad(*)
$$
is true.  On the other hand, GT cannot prove $A \rightarrow B$.  (Group $\mathbb Z/2$ satisfies $A$ but not $B$).  Thus
$$
\textrm{GT}\vdash A\rightarrow B\quad\quad(**)
$$
is false.

---

Advice:  Don't try to understand logic applied to arithmetic, until you already understand logic applied to more mundane topics (like group theory).

Comment: To the OP: there's an important difference between this answer and mine in terms of "flavor:" how difficult it is to analyze provability claims. Specifically, **any** nonprovability claim about a theory implies that theory's consistency. The consistency of $\mathsf{GT}$ doesn't demand much from our metatheory, nor does the fact that $\mathsf{GT}\not\vdash\forall x(x^2=e)$. However, the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$ does at least make us *aware* of the metatheory. Our answers are getting at the same phenomenon, but with different metatheoretical commitments.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ... That's a good point.  My proofs that $(*)$ is true and $(**)$ is false used different models of the theory.  But when we are talking about PA, it is hard to think of models other than the standard one!

Comment: Yeah, sorry to split hairs but I like making this point: it's not that somehow a theory like $\mathsf{GT}$ is amenable to a different kind of metareasoning than $\mathsf{PA}$, the same arguments work for each, it's just that one particular step which is trivial for $\mathsf{GT}$ is hard for $\mathsf{PA}$ (I feel like this helps demystify $\mathsf{PA}$). (+1 btw)

Answer (score 1):

While $(ii)\rightarrow (i)$ is easy to establish per the comments, the other direction breaks down in general - because our metatheory might be too strong for its results to "reflect" down to $\mathsf{PA}$.

(That said, if we're careful about our metatheory we may indeed salvage $(i)\rightarrow (ii)$. But usually we work in a metatheory much stronger than $\mathsf{PA}$ unless explicitly stated otherwise.)

---

An expression like $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash A\quad\implies \mathsf{PA}\vdash B$$ is proved in the metatheory, and that metatheory may be much stronger than $\mathsf{PA}$. For example, what if we accept in the metatheory that $\mathsf{PA}$ is sound? Then our metatheory vacuously accepts $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg Con(\mathsf{PA})\quad\implies\mathsf{PA}\vdash \perp$$ (because it rejects the antecedent), but on the other hand it *also* knows $$\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash (\neg Con(\mathsf{PA}))\rightarrow \perp.$$ This is because "$\neg Con(\mathsf{PA})\rightarrow \perp$" is $\mathsf{PA}$-provably (indeed, purely logically) equivalent to $Con(\mathsf{PA})$, and our metatheory knows via Godel that $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash Con(\mathsf{PA})$.

So actually this is a very strong failure of $(i)\rightarrow (ii)$ in general:

> If our metatheory is strong enough, it establishes an **explicit instance** of $(i)$ holding and $(ii)$ failing.